# Features to import content types

Tags: migrations, features

Features seem to be the right way to import custom centent type in a fresh D7 install from a D6.
But when I create my feature on the D6 one, it added dependencies like modules,and once I import the module on D7, these aren't satisfied because D7 module version doesn't yet exist or it's not recognized..

How can I figure out this ? it's about CCK submodules (filefield,imagefield..)

thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are simply trying to migrate the content type (not the content) then it'll probably be easier to recreate it from scratch than trying to use Features as a migration tool, which is not what it's meant for.

If you want to go down the migration route the natural approach would be to upgrade a copy of your D6 site to D7, but in my experience that'll take longer and be more problematic.

Comment: i did some upgrade tests and it's longer and difficult...so you recommand to install a fresh D7 then, create content type by hand and use migrate module to import content in it ?

Comment: I believe the Feeds module is to be preferred for content import now, but otherwise, yes. (I usually write my own migration code, but that's me).

Comment: but i read about migrate and it seem to be the future to upgrade drupal..?!

Comment: Well, I haven't used either so you may well be right. I think I confused Migrate with something else I've never used :) Looks like it has what you'll need from the project page.

Answer (score 0):

These modules are now in core in D7.

EDIT:

I think I now understand what you are trying to do, and it is going to be a little more difficult than simply upgrading your site to D7. If I understand correctly, you are taking a D6 module generated by Features, and trying to plug it into a D7 site. Before you can do that you MUST first upgrade the D6 module to a D7 module. You will find more information [here](http://drupal.org/update/modules/6/7). The Drupal API has changed for D7.

If this is only a small site, do a clean install in D7, create your content types manually, and use cut and paste to migrate your content. For larger sites, create a complete working copy on a test bed and do a site upgrade following the instructions found [here](http://drupal.org/upgrade).

I have done several d6 -> d7 upgrades, and it usually takes two or three tries to get it right. If you do multiple backups during the process, you can restore to a working stage and continue without having to start from scratch if the upgrade fails for whatever reason.

Good luck.

Comment: so why feature tel me they are missing ?

Comment: You have to activate the modules. They are not active by default.

Comment: agree with you but here feature make difference between disabled module and missing module..so i can't activate missing module at all..and D7 version doesn't exist or they are in core..

Comment: Go to /admin/modules and under 'Core' activate the Image module and all its dependencies.

Comment: done but missing others :
`Dependency Statut
Content Taxonomy Activé
content_taxonomy_options Missing
Date Activé
emvideo Missing
Features Activé
fieldgroup Missing
filefield Missing
imagefield Missing
Link Activé
Node Activé
nodereference Missing
View reference Désactivé`

Comment: These are not in core. Install them, then activate them.

Comment: but filefield ,as example, doesn't exist for D7,idem for nodereference